# Python Selenium - Display all available options in a drop down menu list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to display all available options in a drop down menu list, but they seem to appear only when scrolled till the end. Originally only 10 options are visible, but when scrolling below more options appear.

Opening drop down menu:

```
open_camera_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.chakra-button.chakra-menu__menu-button.css-1419shu')))
open_camera_dropdown.click()
```

Listing available options:

```
camera_options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.css-12j7z0z-option, div.css-1wvw4xx-option")
camera_names = [option.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.chakra-text.css-3x00ox").text for option in camera_options]

print("\nAvailable cameras:")
for index, camera_name in enumerate(camera_names, 1):
   print(f"{index}. {camera_name}")
```

I have tried to perform a scroll, but it doesn't act as expected:

```
camera_dropdown_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-12j7z0z-option, div.css-1wvw4xx-option')))
    
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(camera_dropdown_element)
actions.click_and_hold().move_by_offset(0, 200).release().perform()
```

Note: camera_dropdown_element is an element located within the drop down menu

Despite these attempts, the scrolling method doesn't seem to work reliably as it's not fully loading all the available camera options. I'm seeking guidance on how to overcome this issue and ensure that all the options are displayed before listing them. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code as I don't have the webPage information, but

- For Alternate Approach you can use Javascript commands with help of `execute_script` method.
- Some operations like scrolling down in a page or menu cannot be performed by Selenium methods directly but can be  achieved with Javascript Executor.

  ```
  #Inspect the menu, which you want to scroll
  scrollbox = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,....)
  last_ht, ht = 0, 1
  while last_ht != ht:
      last_ht = ht
      sleep(1)
      ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
           arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);
           return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
           """, scrollbox)
      links = scrollbox.find_elements(...)
  ```

this will scroll down the menu and load another 10 or no. of items and when there
will be nothing left to scroll and height will be equal to this last height i.e
`lt = ht`
break condition , will break loop and you can find elements in that section to
have all options.
You can google more about how to execute javascript commands in python selenium.